# How to set vlc player as default player in windows programmatically?

Tags: python, windows, registry, mp3, vlc

I want to set vlc player as default player for mp3 files on windows OS. For example, if I run a mp3 file via command it should play via vlc player.

Is there any command line or registry settings available to set vlc as default player in windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this *may* work but I haven't tested it.

This program should run the windows commands from within a python script.

```
import os

os.system('assoc .mp3=mp3')
os.system('FTYPE mp3=PATH/TO/VLC.exe')
```

This was taken from the [Microsoft forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/06d35f90-56cb-4dec-b326-bd471d06acee/change-default-program-for-file-command-line-or-registry?forum=w7itprogeneral).

```
Use FTYPE {fileType}={commandString} to create a file type and associated command to open the file.
Use ASSOC {.fileExtension}={fileType} to associate a file extension with the file type you created.
```

Comment: Did this answer help?